# sql:connect is not available

Tags: java, sql, xslt, saxon

I am using SaxonEE to connect xslt with database.i have saxonEE with trail license but when i run the result is sql:connect is not available
This is the config.xml file

```
<configuration 
    xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration" 
    edition="EE" 
    licenseFileLocation="saxon-license.lic">
    <xslt> 
        <extensionElement namespace="http://saxon.sf.net/sql" factory="net.sf.saxon.option.sql.SQLElementFactory"/> 
    </xslt>
</configuration>
```

This is the xslt file

```
  <xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:sql="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:java="http://saxon.sf.net/java-type"
    extension-element-prefixes="saxon sql"

>   
    <xsl:param name="driver" select="'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'"/> 
    <xsl:param name="database" select="'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/Hr'"/> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="not(element-available('sql:connect'))"> 
            <xsl:message>sql:connect is not available</xsl:message> 
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:variable name="connection"> 
            <sql:connect driver="{$driver}" database="{$database}" user="'root'" password="'root'"></sql:connect> 
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="partner"> 
            <sql:query connection="$connection" table="Partner" column="*" row-tag="Partner" column-tag="col"/> 
        </xsl:variable> 

        <Invoice>
            <Header>
                <InvoiceNumber>123456</InvoiceNumber>
                <InvoiceDate>2016-07-15</InvoiceDate>
            </Header>
            <Partners>
                <partner> 
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$partner"/>
                </partner>
            </Partners>
        </Invoice>  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the java code

```
            Source configSource = new StreamSource(new File(configPath));
            EnterpriseConfiguration config = new EnterpriseConfiguration();
            config.readConfiguration(configSource);
            EnterpriseTransformerFactory factory = new EnterpriseTransformerFactory(config);

            Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File(inputXSL));
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

            Source text = new StreamSource(new File(dataXML));
            transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File(outputHTML)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the saxon9-sql.jar file isn't on your classpath.

It would help to know how it is failing.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Michael .. I added it as a jar file in the project but i did not work

Comment: As I say, it would help to know how it is failing.